# Run some script upon internet connection

Tags: wimax

I have a **HUAWEI BM632w** WIMAX modem/router. I wonder is there any way to run some script upon modem connection to internet on remote host or at least send some signal for some where and let them know I am on again?

Imagine all PCs connected to internet using this modem are off and only our modem is on and running.

Answer (score 1):

You can run an IM client on the system, most of them can indicate on-line status.

Comment: Thanks, but would you please tell more about it?

Comment: May I use port forwarding or such things?

Comment: You just run any of the commonly available IM applications on the system you want to track the online status of and then can track its status with either a corresponding IM client or even something along the lines of http://www.imwrapper.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find much info about HUAWEI BM632w but most of Huawei's devices run a very closed  software. Its pretty hard to have startup scripts with such devices.

My best guess to why you would want to do such a thing would be to find out the IP address that was assigned to this device, remotely so you could get in and do some stuff. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

See if this device has any options related to dynamic dns in the settings to help you out. I don't suppose you can get a static IP from the ISP with wireless internet. If you do end up having a dynamic dns or a static ip setup, you could have some kind of script somewhere on remote servers to periodically pool data / ping from that location to see if the device is online.